# Connect to Firebase Cloud Messaging is not working in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am trying to add Firebase Cloud Messaging and Notifications in my current application. Everything is setup correctly according to Firebase docs. I am successfully getting device token in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method but after that when i call `connectToFcm` method I am getting this error:

> [FIRInstanceID cachedCheckinPreferences]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155af9c0

and xcode terminate my app.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FIRInstanceID cachedCheckinPreferences]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155af9c0'

I am not getting what's wrong with my code. Please help me.

Appdelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Firebase.h"

@interface AppDelegate (){

    NSString *InstanceID;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    [FIRApp configure];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    NSLog(@"userInfo=>%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
NSLog(@"deviceToken1 = %@",deviceToken);

}

- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"instanceId_notification=>%@",[notification object]);
InstanceID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[notification object]];

    [self connectToFcm];
}

- (void)connectToFcm {

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError *   _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {

            NSLog(@"InstanceID_connectToFcm = %@", InstanceID);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self connectToFcm];
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be hard to say help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I put my code.

Comment: Do you have swizzling turned on or off?